# BATCH / connect to FTP and put list of directories in an array

Tags: vbscript

I have tried to do this in BAT however I think it cannot be done.

Asked already - Link: [batch-ftp-list-directories-and-put-in-array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29472109/batch-ftp-list-directories-and-put-in-array)

**Objectives:**

- Connect to FTP
- Go to a specific folder `/var/www/xxx.com/image/go`
- List full path of directories and sub directories in that folder
- put the list in an array

I am very new to VBS and it is really not my thing. However BATCH seems to be limited with FTP functions.

```
echo user xxx> c:\cmd.dat
echo 1234>> c:\cmd.dat
echo cd /var/www/xxx/html/TEST>> c:\cmd.dat
echo ls * c:\list.txt>> c:\cmd.dat
echo bye>> c:\cmd.dat
ftp -n -s:c:\cmd.dat xxx xxx xxx

REM This reads a file called list.txt and makes and array


REM - Removes blank lines   
For /F "tokens=* delims=" %%A in (c:\list.txt) Do (
Echo %%A >> c:\list_clean.txt )

pause
set "file=c:\list.txt"
set /A i=0

for /F "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("%file%") do (
set /A i+=1
call echo %%i%%
call set array[%%i%%]=%%a
call set n=%%i%%
)

for /L %%i in (1,1,%n%) do call echo %%array[%%i]%%

pause
del c:\cmd.dat
del c:\wfslist.txt
```

I need to add these fictions:

Comment: There is [ftp.exe](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/ftp.mspx?mfr=true) that you can call from batch scripts. Have you tried working with that?

Comment: @Tomalak Yes, of course. I have used ftp.exe and I cannot find any function to list all the directories. Maybe there is a more advanced ftp.exe for windows, I have looked but no joy.

Comment: Read the documentation again. Look at the -s parameter.

Comment: -s:filename - Specifies a text file containing ftp commands; the commands will automatically run after ftp starts. No spaces are allowed in this parameter. Use this switch instead of redirection (>).  Does this mean you can use all the local command when connected via FTP? I.e. `dir /a:d /b > list.txt`  I tried and it came up with invalid command.

Comment: Yes, that's what it means.

Comment: Could you provide and example code please. I am going to add what I have so far.

Comment: Hm, your approach doesn't look too bad. What's wrong with it?

Comment: it outputs the folder and the files. I only need the folder please.

Comment: You can redirect the output of ftp.exe into a file. After that you can use [`for /f` with a `skip` parameter](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) to cut off unwanted lines.

Comment: You can also use `for /f "skip=X" %%l in ('%command%') do echo %%l` to skip X lines while saving the temporary file (`%command%` would be your ftp.exe call).

Comment: Thanks, let me give it a shot.

Comment: Also, if all else fails, download WinSCP, which is a more fully featured FTP command line client than ftp.exe. BTW, VBScript does not have built-in FTP capabilities. That means doing FTP from VBScript will boil down to calling the same command line programs and parsing their output. You can just as well stay with batch script for basic tasks like a directory listing.

Comment: I agree with you. I shall work on it and if you could look over it, that would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: No problem, will do. If you have something that works, post it as an answer straight away. (I've tried reproducing your situation with  random public FTP servers, but they all require passive mode, which ftp.exe does not support.)

Comment: If you like to post you an example in batch that can list only files from a folder located on a public ftp server like ftp.microsoft.com in order to create a list.txt file to download it after ?

Answer (score 3):

This an example in batch just for testing that can list only files from a folder located on **a public ftp server like ftp.microsoft.com** in order to create a list.txt file to download it after, so give a try and tell us the result.

**NB : Please don't forget to add the tag Batch**

```
@echo off
mode con cols=85 lines=22 & Color A
::***********************************
Set FTPSERVER=ftp.microsoft.com
Title Lister les fichiers et les dossiers sur un serveur FTP (%FTPSERVER%) by Hackoo
Set USER=anonymous
Set Password=anonymous@anonymous.com
Set DossierFTP=/bussys/winsock/winsock2/
Set DownloadFolder=winsock2
::*******************************************************
Goto Lister
:Lister
> ft.do echo Open %FTPSERVER%
>> ft.do echo %USER%
>> ft.do echo %Password%
>> ft.do echo prompt n
>> ft.do echo bin
>> ft.do echo cd %DossierFTP%
>> ft.do echo ls -h TLIST.txt
>> ft.do echo bye
ftp -s:ft.do
del ft.do
CLS
Color 9B
echo Download la liste
pause
Goto Download
::*********************************************************
:Download
> ft.do echo Open %FTPSERVER%
>> ft.do echo %USER%
>> ft.do echo %Password%
>> ft.do echo prompt n
>> ft.do echo bin
>> ft.do echo cd %DossierFTP%
for /F %%f in (TLIST.txt) do ( >> ft.do echo get %%f) 
>> ft.do echo bye
ftp -s:ft.do
del ft.do
CLS
Color 9A
pause
echo Deplacer la liste
Goto Deplacer
::*********************************************************
:Deplacer
Set Source=%~dp0
Set Destination=%Source%%DownloadFolder%
if not exist %DownloadFolder% MD %DownloadFolder%
for /F %%f in (TLIST.txt) do (move "%Source%%%f" "%Destination%")
pause
```

Comment: Hello, @hackoo It does not do what I want it to do however 1+. Please have a look at my code. It will be their in a moment.  You script is useful for other stuff :)

Comment: Very nice, very nice indeed.

Comment: Is there a way to get `echo ls *` to echo the full path please? This will save a lot of coding. I have tired many `ls *,   ls */ etc` or another command. I have also tired DIR as well.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my attempt at it.

This is a utility script that lists a remote directory (full paths, nothing else). It's designed to be reusable (i.e. it works with parameters) and to be called from other scripts.

Save as ftpls.bat.

```
@echo off
setlocal

rem USAGE: call with 4 parameters
rem ftpls hostname USER PASS path/on/remote/machine

set "script=%TEMP%\ftpscript.txt"
set "output=%TEMP%\ftplist.txt"
set "host=%1"
set "user=%2"
set "pass=%3"
set "dir=%4"

>  "%script%" echo open %host%
>> "%script%" echo user %user%
>> "%script%" echo %pass%
>> "%script%" echo cd %dir%
>> "%script%" echo ls * %output%
>> "%script%" echo bye

ftp -n -s:"%script%"

rem modify "skip" and "tokens" to select the right lines and columns
for /f "skip=1 tokens=6,*" %%a in (%output%) do (
  echo %dir%/%%b
)

del "%script%"
del "%output%"
```

The `for` loop cuts out the filename (which is the last part on every line of the listing). Choose the correct `tokens` parameter if `6,*` doesn't work for your FTP server. `6,*` means that column 6 will become `%%a` and the rest of the line (`*`) will become `%%b`. 6 should be the column in front of the filename.

Call it on its own like

```
ftpls xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx USER PASS /var/www/xxx/html/TEST
```

Use it in another batch file like

```
set cmd=ftpls xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx USER PASS /var/www/xxx/html/TEST
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('%cmd%') do (
  echo %%a
)
```